# Read txt file line by line using batch, including lines that start with a semicolon

Tags: windows, batch-file, delimiter

I tried it like this:

```
for /F %%i in (%textfile%) do ( 
echo %%i )
```

Or this:

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do ( 
echo %%i )
```

Or every other combination, with or without tokens or delims.

All of those combinations just echo every line,but for whatever reason excluding the ones starting with a semicolon.
Using a semicolon as a delim defeats the purpous because i can't recognize wich line used to start with a semicolon and wich did not.

If there is any way of correctly reading the lines with a semicolon or recognizing the semicolon lines after they were removed from the delims?

Comment: Use this instead, ```@For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%textfile%") Do @Echo(%%G```. This assumes that you have correctly defined the variable named `textfile`, i.e. ```@Set "textfile=P:\athTo\my file.txt"```. _Please note, that this will still exclude lines with no content_.

Comment: @Compo This works! Thank you! Mind explaining what all the "^" do?

Comment: They escape the character which is directly to their right!

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the default "End Of Line" character `;` by something else:

```
for /f "tokens=* eol=^A" %i in (%textfile%) do @echo %i
```

(in a batch write `%%i` instead of `%i`)

The `^A` is just the content of ASCII/ANSI code 1.
You can obtain it by pressing the modifactor key `alt` and type on the *numeric keypad*  `0001`.

That's a character that rarely will appear in a text file. But your're free to choose a different one.

---

Re-Edit: As *Compo* pointed out in the comments, in fact for the solution there is no EOL character required. So no character will be blocked:

```
for /f tokens^=*^ eol^= %i in (%textfile%) do @echo %i
```

As *jeb* correctly mentioned, one cannot use the obligatory quotes here. So the special interpreted characters `=` and  (space) have to be escaped by the `^`.

At *Compo*'s solution, also the field `delims` is set to 'empty' so the `tokens` option is not necessary in that case.

Comment: OK, I see the point, that one can define *no* character as EOL. The positive effects of `usebackq` is true, but not in the focus of the question. So I concentrated on that.

Comment: Your sample with `for /f "tokens=* eol="` will use the quote as eol character. Only the strange Version from Compo disables the eol character

Comment: @jeb  you're right. I didn't test the `"`as EOL.. A pitty that the cmd shell does not give an error because of the missing `"` that has been eaten by the `eol="`. — Nice construct...